# Exclude objects with generic foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model (simplified) where the warnings model is a generic foreign key which can include Occasion objects (but also other types)

```
Occasion(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()


Warnings(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I want to retrieve any occasion that doesn't have any warnings but also exclude any occasion that has status='new' in the warnings table. How should I write this query?

EDIT: This is the SQL that gets the correct result

```
select * from occasion left join warnings 
on occasion.id = warnings.object_id 
and warnings.content_type_id = 13 --type id for the model.
and warnings.status <> 'new';
```

EDIT again:

This is how I solved it:

```
#First get any occasions with status='new' from warnings
ctype = ContentType.objects.get(app_name="myapp", model="ocassion")

warnings = warning.objects.filter(content_type=ctype, status='new')

#Filter out only object_ids
warning_occasion_list = set(list(warnings.values_list('object_id', flat=True))

#Then exclude these from the occasion query
occasions = occasion.objects.all().exclude(occasion_id__in=warning_occasion_list)
```